# mysql. how to show value not same from 2 table

Tags: mysql

this my table **t1 and t2**

```
t1               t2  
+----+--------+  +----+--------+
| id | name   |  | id | name   |
+----+--------+  +----+--------+
|  1 | chair1 |  | 1  | chair1 |
|  2 | chair2 |  | 3  | chair3 |
|  3 | chair3 |  +----+--------+
+----+--------+
```

how to show not same value between t1 and t2. i'm try use join and union but not working. i want result like this.

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  2 | chair2 |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: What's your own thought? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without `JOIN`s or `UNION`s by using `NOT IN` and a subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t2)
```

The subquery will select all the `id`s from t2. The rest of the query will select rows which don't appear from the subquery.

Comment: What's wrong with JOINs?